# Getting PHP variable to jquery script file by AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So basically i have two files. 1 is my php file and it creates tables with some variables when it's called, and second file is jquery script file that makes that call. My script file:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: ({p:2,ank : ankieta,wybrane:wybrane}),
                url: 'zestawienia_db.php',
                success: function(data) {

                     $('#results').html(data);
  }
        });
```

and it works fine by printing my results. 
My php file is echoing data that should be printed in my results div.
**Question is how to get some PHP data variables and be able to use them in my jquery file without actually echoing them ??**

Comment: You can't, differents languages, differents purposes, one is a script client side, another is interpreted server side. The only way to do this is by echoing the PHP variables, but you can echoing the variables on a script tag, so you can access it from the javascript, but no using them directly. You could even set the response of the AJAX call in JSON and make what you need from there.

Comment: There is no other way. You have to transmit the data to JavaScript explicitly. As mentioned, however, you could use the JSON data format to send a complex data object instead of raw HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like i said in my comment to your question, a way to do that is by echoing the variables on a script tag, so you can access in javascript.

```
<script>
var PHPVariables;
PHPVariables.VariableName1 = '<?=$phpVariableName1?>';
PHPVariables.VariableName2 = '<?=$phpVariableName2?>';
PHPVariables.VariableName3 = '<?=$phpVariableName2?>';
</script>
```

And you could use those values accessing `PHPVariables.VariableName1` on the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by echoing all the data you want like so peiceofdata§anotherpeice§onemorepeice§anotherpeice then you can use php's explode function and use § for the "exploding char" this will make an array of all the above data like this somedata[0] = peiceofdata somedata[1] = anotherpeice and so on.

the explode function is used like this

explode('§', $somestringofinfoyouwanttoturnintoanarray);

you can then echo the relevent data like so
echo data[0];
which in this case wiill echo the text peiceofdata.

Answer (score 1):

Use json format, and in this json add your data variables :

PHP :

```
$arr = array('var1' => $var1, 'var2' => $var2, 'var3' => $var3);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Javascript :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: ({p:2,ank : ankieta,wybrane:wybrane}),
    url: 'zestawienia_db.php',
    success: function(data) {
      data = JSON && JSON.parse(data) || $.parseJSON(data);
      $('#results1').html(data.var1);
      $('#results2').html(data.var2);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thx for effort but it wouldn't work with my code, cause i need to print all data first.

Comment: @norbidrak if you want to print all data first, save all data in a key of the json like this : `array('allData' => $allData, 'otherdata' => $otherdata);`. And print like this : `$('#results').html(data.allData); `. After if you want to get an access to an specific variable add this to the json.

Comment: True, but in my case allData are dynamically created divs with tables, cells and multiple variables, i can't squeeze it all into one variable. I find a way around by sending hidden inputs and naming desired fields so i can get values from them using jquery selectors.

Answer (score 1):

write this type of code in ajax file

var data  =array('name'=>'steve', date=>'18-3-2014');

echo jsonencode(data);

//ajax call in this manner

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',

```
data:  pass data array,

url: ajaxfile url,

success: function(data) {

 var data = $.parseJSON(data);

 $('#name').html(data.name);
 $('#date').html(data.date);
}
```

});

Comment: Kyaa baat hai Ritesh :)